# How to stream a content of video file to network using h264 over rtp ? cmd line commands please

Tags: linux, video

What command can I use to stream the contents of a video file over the network using H.264 over RTP?

Comment: You want to serve the file or play the file from a remote?

Answer (score 0):

I used vlc player to stream file. Question answered.

Comment: Perhaps you can show an example?

Answer (score 0):

In vlc player, open network protocol (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) and type 
`rtp://ip:port/file_path`

ex:

```
rtp://192.168.1.52:2000/movies/test.mp4
```